# Layer error: reduce.median: 'Can't apply calendarRange filter to objects without a timestamp'

Tags: google-earth-engine, error

I´m trying to end this script. It has worked perfectly for other two time range, but for Landsat 5 and Landsat8.

When i tried do the same for LANDSAT7 this error occurred:

> Layer error: reduce.median: 'Can't apply calendarRange filter to objects without a timestamp'.

PART OF MY SCRIPT:

```
var L7coll = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filterBounds(region)
  .filterDate(startDateL7,endDateL7)
  .map(fDeleteClouds)
  .map(landMask)

//Corrigindo as imagens do Landsat5 a partir de 2003 (que são "riscadas")
  .map(function(image){
                var filled1a = image.focal_mean(2, 'square', 'pixels', 1)
                return filled1a.blend(image);
}) 

...

var wet_2001 = L7coll.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(10,3,'month'));
var wet_2001_median= wet_2001.median();
var dry_2001 = L7coll.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(4,9,'month'));
var dry_2001_median= dry_2001.median();

...

Map.addLayer(wet_2001[1],vizParams,'2001_dry_1');
Map.addLayer(dry_2001[1],vizParams,'2001_wet_1');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, when a function is applied, the result lost its properties. The solution is to copy image properties to the new file. In this case, `system:time_start`:

```
var fill = function(image){
                var filled1a = image.focal_mean(2, 'square', 'pixels', 1).blend(image);
                return filled1a.set('system:time_start',image.get('system:time_start'));
};

var L7coll = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filterBounds(region)
  .filterDate(startDateL7,endDateL7)
  .map(fDeleteClouds)
  .map(landMask)
  .map(fill);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly!!